# How to get a combined count on two tables for shared id

Tags: sql

I have two transcript tables, A_Transcript and B_Transcript, and I want a query that will give me all the users who have more than 2 total transcripts (across both tables). Thanks!

Here's the query if I just had one table with data:

---

`select user_Id, count(*) From A_Transcript
group by user_ID
having count(*) > 2;`

Comment: schema of both table please . you can use inner join and then count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the full list of userids from both tables before grouping, and you need UNION ALL to do a non-distinct union:

```
SELECT user_Id, count(*)
FROM
(
     SELECT user_Id
     FROM A_Transcript a
     UNION ALL
     select user_Id
     FROM B_Transcript b
) combined
GROUP BY user_Id
HAVING COUNT(*) >2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just union the 2 queries together.

```
SELECT user_Id, count(*) FROM A_Transcript
GROUP BY user_ID
HAVING count(*) > 2
UNION
SELECT user_Id, count(*) FROM B_Transcript
GROUP BY user_ID
HAVING count(*) > 2
```

Comment: Something along these lines...but this query seems to miss people who I'd like to get who have, for example, 1 transcript in A_Transcript and 2 transcripts in B_Transcript.